# Per-Channel do-not-disturb on Slack?

Tags: notifications, slack

It appears that Slack's do-not-disturb feature is on a team-by-team basis. I would prefer to disable this for certain channels though. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure your notification settings per channel in Slack. Just go to the respective channel, click on the cog symbol and then on "Notification Preferences". There you can also mute the channel completely.

However, its not possible the overwrite the "dnd" state for specific channels that way.

Comment: A surprising lack of per-channel policy controls...